# webcenter iframe issues

Tags: iframe, webcenter

I am using WebCenter and I am using iframe to open a document in the a separate frame below the links. When I try to do this it includes the home page frames instead of just loading the document content. So I end up with the frames from the home page with the new document in the middle surrounded by the home page frames again. How to stop the home page frames from showing up and just get the document page to load? I just want the bottom frame to refresh and display the content.

Any ideas

-Joe

Comment: Webcenter UCM?
Webcenter Portal?
Webcenter Spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Page Template without any of the stuff you don't want.

Then, create a new space that is not nested inside the main space.  Call it something like minimal space.  Then add the pages you want framed-in to the new space which has its own page template.

That will do what you want.